# How to add error message while add new custom post and edit custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to add error message on custom field in custom post save action But my validation not working. Check my code below.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_event_meta_data' );

function save_event_meta_data( $post_id ) {


 $event_university = $_POST['event_university'];


 if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'tribe_events' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
 }

 if($event_university=="") {

        new WP_Error( 'Error', __( "Please select university" ) );
        return;
 }

 $event_university_data = $event_university ;
 update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event_university', $event_university_data );   


}
```

please do the needful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying error message on other page, you need to save it in some variable. So try below code.

```
if($event_university=="") {
     global $error;
     $error = new WP_Error();
     $error->add("Please select university");
     return;
}
```

Then on the other page you can access that error message using below code:

```
global $error;
echo $error->get_error_message();
```